# How to group elements of Timeline in typescript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, associative-array, timeline

I have an existing code that build a timeline view of different stages & their steps for a given array of stage. Each stage contains its name, step & status.
I need to group these stages by their name and display its steps grouped by stage name.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Timeline } from 'antd';
:

const stageDiv = styled.div`
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
`;

const stepDiv = styled.div`
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
`;

:

<Timeline ...>
    {stages.map((stage: any, index: number) => (
        <TimelineItem key={`${stage.StageName}-${index}`}>
            <stageDiv>{stage.StageName}</stageDiv>
            <stepDiv>{stage.step}</stepDiv>
        </TimelineItem>
    ))}
</Timeline>
```

For following input:

```
stages = [
    {
        StageName: A,
        Step: <First-Step of A>.
        Status: Done,
    }, 
    {
        StageName: A,
        Step: <Second-Step of A>.
        Status: Pending,
    },
    {
        StageName: A,
        Step: <Third-Step of A>.
        Status: Failed,
    },
    {
        StageName: B,
        Step: <First-Step of B>.
        Status: Done,
    },
    {
        StageName: B,
        Step: <Second-Step of B>.
        Status: Done,
    }
    {
        StageName: C,
        Step: <First-Step of C>.
        Status: Pending,
    }
]
```

It builds timeline like

```
o   A
|   <First-Step of A>
|
o   A
|   <Second-Step of A>
|
o   A
|   <Third-Step of A>
|
o   B
|   <First-Step of B>
|
o   B
|   <Second-Step of B>
|
o   C
    <First-Step of C>
```

I need to group these stages by their name and build timeline like

```
o   A
|   <First-Step of A>
|
|   <Second-Step of A>
|
|   <Third-Step of A>
|
o   B
|   <First-Step of B>
|
|   <Second-Step of B>
|
o   C
    <First-Step of C>
```

I have tried

```
function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (arr, obj) {
    let key = obj[property]
    if (!arr[key]) {
      arr[key] = []
    }
    arr[key].push(obj)
    return arr
  }, [])
}

function ({ stages }: any) {
    let groupedStages = groupBy(stages, 'StageName')
    :
    :

    <Timeline ...>
    {Object.entries(groupedStages).forEach(([stageName, stageSteps]) => (
      <TimelineItem key={stageName}>
        <stageDiv>{stageName}</stageDiv>
        {stageSteps.map((stageStep: any, index: number) => (
            <stepDiv>{stageStep.step}</stepDiv>
        ))}
      </TimelineItem>
    ))}
}
```

But this is not working. How can I group and display these stage steps?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote your code in online javascript it works in my case. can you check my code? it helps you a lot.

```
const stageArray = stages = [
    {
        "StageName": "A",
        "Step": "<First-Step of A>",
        "Status": "Done",
    }, 
    {
        "StageName": "A",
        "Step": "<Second-Step of A>",
        "Status": "Pending",
    },
    {
        "StageName": "A",
        "Step": "<Third-Step of A>",
        "Status": "Failed",
    },
    {
        "StageName": "B",
        "Step": "<First-Step of B>",
        "Status": "Done",
    },
    {
        "StageName": "B",
        "Step": "<Second-Step of B>",
        "Status": "Done",
    },
    {
        "StageName": "C",
        "Step": "<First-Step of C>",
        "Status": "Pending",
    }
];


function groupBy(objectArray, property) {
  return objectArray.reduce(function (arr, obj) {
    let key = obj[property]
    if (!arr[key]) {
      arr[key] = []
    }
    arr[key].push(obj)
    return arr
  }, [])
}

let groupedStages = groupBy(stages, 'StageName');


Object.entries(groupedStages).forEach(([stageName, stageSteps]) => {
    console.log(stageName);
     stageSteps.map((stageStep, index) => {
        console.log(stageStep.Step);
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: I am also able to do console.log. But it does not work with <Timeline>, <div> & other tags `<Timeline ...>
    {Object.entries(groupedStages).forEach(([stageName, stageSteps]) => (
      <TimelineItem key={stageName}>
        <stageDiv>{stageName}</stageDiv>
        {stageSteps.map((stageStep: any, index: number) => (
            <stepDiv>{stageStep.step}</stepDiv>
        ))}
      </TimelineItem>
    ))}`

Comment: can you share your files, I'll check it

Comment: I can't share file for legal reasons. You can check code snippet at https://paste.ac/amr2PzV

Comment: ok, no problem, I'll check on my free time